# How to select holidays in PHP?

Tags: php, scheduling

I have a holiday class that contains a multidimensional array of holidays with different time periods that works basically like this:

```
$this->bgArray = array( 'background' => array(
                                    array(  'name'  => 'SuperBowl', 
                                            'start' => '06 Feb 2011', 
                                            'end'   => '07 Feb 2011'),

                                    array(  'name'  => 'presidentsday2011', 
                                            'start' => '21 Feb 2011', 
                                            'end'   => '22 Feb 2011'),

                                    array(  'name'  => 'marchmadness6', 
                                            'start' => '01 Mar 2011', 
                                            'end'   => '02 Mar 2011')));
```

and when it is called I want to be able to select the right holiday and run subsequent code, currently I have that set up as:

```
foreach($holidays->bgArray['background'] AS $holiday)
    {
        if (($holidays->today >= strtotime($holiday['start']) && $holidays->today < strtotime($holiday['end']) || (isset($_REQUEST[$holiday['name']])) ))
        {
            $background = $holiday['name'];
        }
    }

    $this->set_background($background);
```

this code is all working great but personally I feel like there is a better way to do this code than a foreach loop. Does anyone have any suggestions? Also, no I don't have access to a DB so I have to this all within PHP. Any help is appreciated, thanks guy.

Comment: *and when it is called I want to be able to select the right holiday* | *What* is called when? What is the input?

Comment: What about holidays that aren't on fixed days, e.g. Easter, or Labor Day, but rather at some offset from some other event, like spring equinox.

Comment: Depending on today's date, looks like they'd be setting the background of the HTML page or something. Let's ask this, though: how many events are there going to be? If there aren't too many, does the efficiency/beauty of this matter? If you're going to add a lot, maybe use user-defined sorting functions to sort by dates and try search functions on the array? (Just general ideas.) Oh, and if you would want a database (allowing a simple search on the date fields) without a dedicated server try SQlite.

Comment: @Felix Kling when I call this background class, which is the array above provided. I call the class which contains that multidimensional array and then I run the foreach loop on it to select the right holiday.

Comment: @Marc B I won't have to worry about dates like this since I'll only be doing dates that run at some sort of range, thanks for some additional cases to think about though.

Comment: @Guttsy thanks so much for the reply, you are correct it will be setting a background on an HTML page. I would say the list of events runs about 25 deeps, beauty isn't top priority but efficiency is primarily what I'm worried about. Sadly I have zero options for a database on this, but what about an external XML? Would that be easier to run through, search data for then this foreach loop through an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach is fine for arrays. You might want to use unix timestamps directly in your array since always using strtotime isn't excactly the fastest way.

What you also could do is splitting the array up into months, having a subarray for each month. That way you don't have to iterate over all holidays but only the specific ones for the month to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice, great ideas all around, I particularly like the unix timestamps directly, could cut back on function calls. I appreciate the help.